# ImageView hides the round corners of the parent

Tags: java, android

I have a CardView as parent and inside the CardView I have a ConstraintLayout and defined a border for the ConstraintLayout.  But the problem is that the border disappears when it reaches the imageView I put inside ConstraintLayout and it can't be seen anymore

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3XYN.jpg
[image: two muppets]

Now to fix this problem, I set the top and bottom and right margins as 1dp for imageView because my border is 1dp wide, but still the problem is that the corner angle has a problem and gets narrow and is not displayed clearly

[image: two muppets]

By the way, I don't want to use cardElevation

item code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cv_item_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pc_corners_parent_gray_stroke">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_avatar"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wqe" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_item_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_item_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="4.0 ★"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_tiny_other"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

corners code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorCardViewsBackgroundSet" android:dashWidth="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Did you try using just a simple margin?

Comment: Just a suggestion, did you try to put the ImageView inside a CardView?

Comment: Np, i'll write it as an answer for future developers to see

Comment: @GauravMall tanks but it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the ImageView inside a CardView and it should keep the corners round.
I am not sure if it's the best way to go about it but it works.